# How to construct std::wstring_view from two std::wstring::const_iterator-s?

Tags: c++17

What is the right way to implement the following function that creates std::wstring_view from two std::wstring iterators (pointing to the same std::wstring)?

```
std::wstring_view MakeStringView(std::wstring::const_iterator begin, std::wstring::const_iterator end)
{
    //How to implement it?
}
```

Comment: The constructors can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view). Does that help?

Comment: @Barry yes, thank you! It helps!